# Crop an image after capture in samsung galaxy S4

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-image

I am trying to crop an image after capturing it from the camera. My code is working fine on S2 and other android phones but i'm not able to figure out why it is not working on S4. I've tried to crop an image from the gallery but still i'm not able to do circleCrop in that case and also tried to put  com.android.camera.action.CROP on the intent, but still it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());

intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 350);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 350);
intent.putExtra("circleCrop", "true");
intent.putExtra("scale", true);

intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Comment: There is no `CROP` `Intent` in Android: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Okay.. but i have also tried the code that i have mentioned above..
This code is working fine on Samsung Galaxy S2 and other android phones but i am unable to crop on Samsung Galaxy S4 using the same code...

Comment: There are over 1,000 different Android devices. Have you bought them all? Have you tried them all? What makes you think that an undocumented set of random extras will work for all of those devices' default `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` handlers? How do you plan to force developers worldwide to support those extras for *every* implementation of an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity, in case users actually dare to download other apps that support this action?

Comment: I didn't mean to say like that.. actually i am a beginner in android development. I have tried this code in 2-3 android phones where it was working fine but it didn't work in S4.. I just wanted to know the reason behind it..

Comment: The "reason behind it", most likely, is that Samsung declined to support the same undocumented extras on the S4. There are hundreds of devices, and hundreds of other `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` applications, that will fail to support some or all of those undocumented extras. That is why you should not be assuming that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` offers any cropping capability.

Comment: Guys, Anybody has solution instead of Arguments?